# Triggering eventListeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

By use of [Chrome's API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#geteventlistenersobject) we can use the function

```
getEventListeners(object)
```

to obtain all eventListeners of a certain DOM object.

How would one now go about triggering the acquired mouseClick events after iteration?

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: @zero298 My confusion lays in the fact that I don't have the event, but the eventListener.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: If I'd have the event object I could use `!target.dispatchEvent(event)` to trigger it. But I do not have the event object; I have the EventListener.

Comment: Then **make** an event, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and dispatch `Event`s whenever you want.  Consider the following example.  Since this snippet runs in a browser context, we can't actually use `getEventListeners()`.

```js
// Get an element
const test = document.querySelector(".test");

// Add a listener
test.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("test"));

// Trigger the listener
setTimeout(() => test.click(), 1000);

// Explicit event dispatching
setTimeout(() => {
  const evt = new Event("click");
  test.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 2000);

// Create and dispatch events of every typ attached to element
if (typeof getEventListeners !== "function") {
  console.warn("getEventListeners is unsupported");
} else {
  Object.keys(getEventListeners(test)).forEach(k => {
    const e = new Event(k);
    test.dispatchEvent(e);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Hello</div>
```

So, to boil all that down into a reusable function, we can write:

```
/**
 * Dispatch events for all listeners attached to an element
 * @param {Element} el The element to dispatch events for
 */
function fireAllListeners(el) {
  /* 
   * getEventListeners only works in console, so make 
   * sure we can call it without throwing an exception
   */
  if (typeof getEventListeners !== "function") {
    console.warn("getEventListeners is not supported in this context");
    return
  }

  // Get all the listeners on an element
  const listeners = getEventListeners(el);
  // Get all the types of listeners ("click", "touch", "load", etc)
  const listenerTypes = Object.keys(listeners);
  // Map those listeners and make events for each
  const eventsToFire = listenerTypes.map(lt => new Event(lt));

  // Dispatch all the events
  eventsToFire.forEach(e => el.dispatchEvent(e));
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `else` case? For each eventListener,  we make a new event after which we fire it with dispatchEvent right?
Why are you using a constant type for the new event?

Comment: @MusséRedi Don't let the `const` type bog you down.  In the most basic sense, it's an ES6 way of writing `var` that prevents you from changing the value of `var` accidentally.  The `else` was just to prevent the browser context from throwing an exception since you can't run `getEventListeners` in the actual browser, only in console.

Comment: Well, technically you could use getEventListeners in a Chrome browser if it is implemented via a custom Chrome extension, right? A work-around for using it in a script.

Comment: @MusséRedi Probably, I have not experimented much with the WebExtension API.  However, when I say "browser context", I mean, the JS context of a website that you normally visit.  That context doesn't have the same privileges of the console or a WebExtension (thankfully).

Comment: By browser context, you mean for instance, the functions available in the namespace of the document.defaultView DOM object; the current so-called window?
Wouldn't that context get the same privileges of a console if implemented via a custom Chrome extension?